# Syntax error with running bash script in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following target in a makefile -

```
buildwebapp:
    cp webapp.sha webapp.old.sha
    $(call UpdateWebappHash)
    if cmp -s "webapp.sha" "webapp.old.sha"; then\
        echo "A"\
    else\
        echo "B"\
    fi\
```

When I run this via `make buildwebapp` I get the error-

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Makefile:157: buildwebapp] Error 2
```

The bash part of makefile runs perfectly from a `.sh` file -

```
if cmp -s "webapp.sha" "webapp.old.sha"; then
    echo "A"
else
    echo "B"
fi
```

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong in the makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the error is that shell splits commands by either end of line or `;`. However `GNU make` joins all the code by `\` into one line. So called subshell gets `if cmp -s "webapp.sha" "webapp.old.sha"; then echo "A" else echo "B" fi` and treats the `fi` as an argument of the first `echo`.

You have to terminate both your `echo`s with `;`:

```
buildwebapp:
    cp webapp.sha webapp.old.sha
    $(call UpdateWebappHash)
    if cmp -s "webapp.sha" "webapp.old.sha"; then\
        echo "A";\
    else\
        echo "B";\
    fi\
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` are not newlines. When `make` combines lines with `\`, they will result in a single line. To separate statements on a single line in shell, you will need `;`, like you did between `if` and `then`.

Assuming this is `gmake`, then I suggest you add the target [.ONESHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html). This will execute the whole as a single script and you won't need `\`.